# Atribuir envio de email automático a um botão usando nodemailer

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

Possuo um site e gostaria que quando o usuário enviasse uma mensagem através do contato, o site me enviasse essa mensagem via email... já configurei o envio e está funcionando usando o NODEMAILER

```
    const nodemailer = require ('nodemailer');

var assunto = 'teste';
var nome = 'teste2';
var email = 'teste2@hotmail.com';
var msg = 'teste 2 teste 2 teste 2';

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "mail.example.com",
    port: 465,
    secure: true, 
    auth: {
        user:'meuusuariodoemail@example.com',
        pass:'****minhasenhasupersegura****'
    }
});

transporter.sendMail({
    from: '<meuusuariodoemail@example.com>',
    to: 'contato@example.com',
    subject: assunto,   
    text: 'nome: ' + nome + ' Email: ' + email + ' -- mensagem: ' +msg,

});
```

o form de envio onde tenho o botão de envio do formulário está assim:

```
<form id='contatos'>
    <div class="form-group">
      <h2 id='tituloCont'>Envie sua mensagem</h2>
      <label for="nomeCont" id='labelNome'>Seu nome</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomeCont" placeholder="Digite aqui seu nome">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="motivoCont" id='labelMot'>Qual o motivo do contato ?</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="motivoCont" placeholder="Digite aqui o motivo do seu contato">
    </div>     
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="emailCont" id='labelMot'>Seu Email</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emailCont" placeholder="Digite aqui seu Email">
    </div>     
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="textoCont" id='mensagemCont'>Digite sua mensagem</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="textoCont" rows="4"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button id='enviarCont' onclick="envia()">
      Enviar
    </button>
  </form>
```

imaginei fazer algo do tipo :

```
$('#enviarCont').click(function(){
```

})

e colar dentro disso o código q está enviando o Email... porém não funciona...

Comment: Sim, não funciona, o nodemailer deve ser configurado no backend(nodejs). Você deve expor uma rota publica que chama o envio do e-mail. (via post) para o seu backend. Assim em sua ação de clique basta chamar o endpoint com os dados do form.

Comment: MAs quando eu chamo no prompt o comando  node index.js (nome do arquivo q ta o envio) ele envia o email normalmente...

Comment: Não entendi oq vc quis dizer, será q pode me mostrar ?? estou travada nisso e parece ser algo tão simples

Answer (score 1):

Para criar uma rota em seu backend para tratar envios de email, você vai precisar criar um endpoint para manipular o envio do seu email.

Para isso vamos criar os seguintes passos:

1. Criar um endpoint que faz o envio via o nodemailer
2. Chamar o endpoint em nosso frontend para o email ser enviado

Para criar o nosso servidor, vamos precisar instalar as libs `express` para montar o servidor que vai receber as requisições e o `cors` para liberar o acessso da nossa aplicação para o nosso frontend. Além do `node-mailer`

Para criar o endpoint no backend temos:

***app.js***

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
cors({ credentials: true, origin: true });
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use(require('./server/index'));
module.exports = app;
```

***server/index.js***

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const router = require('express').Router();

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "mail.example.com",
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: 'meuusuariodoemail@example.com',
        pass: '****minhasenhasupersegura****'
    }
});

router.post('/enviaremail', (req, res) => {
    const mailOptions = {
        from: 'meuusuariodoemail@example.com',
        to: req.body.email,
        subject: req.body.assunto,
        text: `Mensagem de: ${req.body.nome}, ${req.body.mensagem}`
    }
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions).then((trans) => {
        res.status(200).json(trans);
    }).catch((error) => {
        res.status(500).json(error);
    })
});
module.exports = router;
```

***bin/www***

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const app = require('../app');
try {
    app.listen(process.env.PORT);
    console.log(`Microsservice listening at http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`);
} catch (err) {
    throw err;
}
```

Após desenvolver essa aplicação no backend, basta apontar o frontend para esta rota e fazer a chamada via ajax. Este código ficaria na ação de clique do seu botão. Os dados que estou deixando hardcoded no request, devem vim do seu formulário html.

```
const axios = require('axios');
axios.post('http://localhost:3000/enviaremail', {
    nome: 'aaaa',
    email: 'a@a.com',
    assunto: 'assunto principal',
    mensagem: 'minha mensagem',
})
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Existem algumas configurações que você deve fazer afim de ter segurança, configure o [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) com algum valor que faça sentido para o seu ambiente. E para os valores que estão hardcoded em meu backend, você deveria utilizar [variáveis de ambiente](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).

Outra funcionalidade que pode implementar é validar os valores do form (no frontend) antes de fazer o submit e validar no backend (antes de fazer o envio). Sim é necessário validar no frontend e backend.